Не работает @media, работаю с ним первый раз
Пытаюсь сделать адаптация для сайта, но страница не реагирует на правило вообще:
.news-item{
  border-color: #f6f6f6;
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 357px;
  padding: 50px 30px 50px 30px;
  min-width: auto;
}
.news-row {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-gap: 15px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1102){
  .news-row {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    grid-auto-flow:row;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .news-item {
    min-width: auto;
  }
}


Скорее всего вы забыли px после 1102

спасибо,  получилось исправить
